# When determining time complexity are variables like n etc always given to an input?

Tags: recursion, binary-tree, big-o

The short version of this long post is when determining time complexity are variables like n etc always given to an input? If not, how else can you define variables?

I'm leaving the long version of my question below in case it helps anyone.

NOTE: I'm aware the question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228896/understanding-big-o-notation-cracking-the-coding-interview-example-9) but I'm not satisfied with the answers. The accepted answer ignores the part of the question that the recursion essentially creates a balanced binary tree, while the second answer wrongly presumes that the author used the input as the definition of n rather than the number of levels of calls in the binary tree. (although it may be making the correct point that the difference is the definition of n and its possible the author slipped up or just confused me instead)

I'm comparing these two examples on edition 6 of Cracking the Coding Interview

Pages 44-45 (VI Big O Recursive Runtime section)

```
int f(int n){
  if (n <= 1){
    return 1;
  }
  return f(n-1) + f(n-1);
}
```

In this case the author defined n as the number of levels created through the recursive calls.

Pages 49-50 (VI Big O Example 9)

Assume the input is a balanced binary search tree

```
int sum(Node node){
  if(node == null){
      return 0;
  }
  return sum(node.left) + node.value + sum(node.right);
}
```

Here the author defines n as the number of nodes in the tree and states that therefore the depth of the tree is log n. (and since 2^logn equals n its O(n)

So here's the number of calls and depth of the tree based on the input in the first example

```
Input Calls Depth (author started counting from 0, used the term levels)
1     1     0
2     2     1
3     7     2
4     15    3
etc
```

I'm actually confused why the author was able to choose the depth of the tree as n because in the past I've always seen an input used as n? (it also seems meaningless b/c the depth is the input minus 1) Was the 2nd answer in the question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45228896/understanding-big-o-notation-cracking-the-coding-interview-example-9) actually correct instead of the author by using the proper definition of n as the input?

In the 2nd example above it seems sensible that n is the number of nodes in the tree and therefore it has the depth of n?

So I guess I'm asking if an input is always the proper criteria for defining n (or whatever term you want to use as the variable)? If not, how else can you define n? If the input is always used to define n I get why the answers would be different. If not, I'd be confused since the recursion in example 1 essentially does create a balanced binary tree which therefore also has a depth of log n.

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you're confused about. `n` is always the size of the input which of course can mean many different things. The first example creates a tree of **depth** `n` with 2^n elements the second has `n` number of elements with log n depth.

Comment: I was just confused by the author choosing to use n as the variable for the equation of how many nodes the recursive tree has. I thought she meant that was n for the problem rather than the input.

Comment: ok, if you have an algorithm that operates on a number that number is going to be `n` (in this case she also called it `int n` but this is not important you can call it `int whatever`)

Answer (score 0):

Based on googling it does seem that n (etc) is supposed to refer to the input.

[Explain Time Complexity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384598/explain-time-complexity)

https://rob-bell.net/2009/06/a-beginners-guide-to-big-o-notation/

https://www.interviewcake.com/article/java/big-o-notation-time-and-space-complexity